# AppleScript: cannot get property of window

Tags: applescript

I'm a newbie in AppleScript.
I'm trying to write a short automator script that involves getting/setting window's `miniaturized` (or `minimized` for some apps apparently).

I'm totally lost at the point: Why the first attempt works but not the second one in the following codes?

```
# Run this, and switch to Google Chrome, within 3 seconds
delay 3

# This works
tell application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/"
    log (get minimized of first window)
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    set process_bid to get the bundle identifier of (first application process whose frontmost is true)
    set application_name to file of (application processes where bundle identifier is process_bid)
end tell
set front_app to POSIX path of (application_name as string)

# They're same
log (front_app = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/")

# Then why is this not working?
tell application front_app
    log (get minimized of first window)
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of `tell application` must be a literal (a constant) because the terminology of the application inside the `tell` block is evaluated at **compile** time.

You could add a `using terms from` block, then the argument of `tell application` can be a variable. But this requires the argument of the block to be a constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That also implies that basically it's impossible to do something like "get a window, minimize it, and remember to un-minimize it back later", because there're no way to "store" a reference to window, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Run this, and switch to Google Chrome, within 3 seconds
delay 3

# This works
tell application id "com.google.Chrome" to log (get minimized of first window)

tell application "System Events"
    set process_bid to bundle identifier of (1st process whose frontmost is true)
end tell

# They're same
log (process_bid = "com.google.Chrome")

log (run script ("tell application id \"" & process_bid & "\" to minimized of window 1"))
```

Another (simple) example for testing:

```
set process_bid to "com.google.Chrome"

run script ("tell application id \"" & process_bid & "\" to minimized of window 1")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also a perfect answer.